# (symbol-name sym) vs. (format "%s" sym)

Tags: symbols

I noticed some code in [use-package-core.el](https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package/blob/a7422fb8ab1baee19adb2717b5b47b9c3812a84c/use-package-core.el#L417) where `format` is used to get a keyword's name as a string,

```
(format "%s" keyword)
```

Is there a reason this is preferable to using `symbol-name`?

```
(symbol-name keyword)
```

I would've expected `symbol-name` to be better in terms of readability and performance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If `KEYWORD` is indeed always a *symbol* (in particular a keyword symbol) then IMO there's no special reason to use `format`. But there's no special reason not to, either: "better readability" is opinion-based, and performance difference is probably negligible.

But if it's *not* sure to be a symbol then using `format` with `"%s"` ensures that the resulting value is a string and not raise an error.

Comment: Good point. I'm not sure whether it's good or bad that this will produce a string rather than an error if `KEYWORD` is something other than a symbol, but it's an aspect I hadn't considered.

Answer (score 4):

> Is there a reason this is preferable to using `symbol-name`?

No, I think it just comes down to style and context.  E.g. I can imagine someone preferring to consistently use `format` everywhere, because it can handle more than just symbols, and the format string can be easily changed.

See also [Drew's answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/64483/15748).

> I would've expected `symbol-name` to be better in terms of readability

That's entirely subjective and context-dependent, I'm afraid.

> and performance.

I'd expect the same.  `symbol-name` just checks that it has a symbol, untags it, and returns the stored name:

```c
DEFUN ("symbol-name", Fsymbol_name, Ssymbol_name, 1, 1, 0,
       doc: /* Return SYMBOL's name, a string.  */)
  (register Lisp_Object symbol)
{
  register Lisp_Object name;

  CHECK_SYMBOL (symbol);
  name = SYMBOL_NAME (symbol);
  return name;
}
```

Although `format` essentially boils down to the same thing for symbols:

```c
/* ... */
if (SYMBOLP (arg))
  {
    spec->argument = arg = SYMBOL_NAME (arg);
    if (STRING_MULTIBYTE (arg) && ! multibyte)
      {
        multibyte = true;
        goto retry;
      }
  }
/* ... */
```

there is a lot more bookkeeping involved, and potentially a string allocation, so it is quite likely to run slower.

Having said that, the time it takes to evaluate `(format "%s" keyword)` should be so miniscule that for all practical purposes there is no performance difference between that and `(symbol-name keyword)`.

As always, it is better to profile your code for performance, rather than trying to reason about minor (and probably premature) optimisations like this.

Another thing to consider when comparing seemingly identical definitions, is whether one or the other has a dedicated opcode (which tends to result in faster execution) or is marked as `pure` or `side-effect-free`.